# Having ObservableCollection Trigger an update

Tags: c#, silverlight

So i have something along the lines of

```
private  ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _internal;

public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> BoundInternal{get;set}; //this is Binded in the Itemssource like ItemSource={Binding BoundInternal}
```

Now In my code i do something like

BoundInternal=_internal, However the problem is the BoundInternal isn't trigger any collectionChanged event. I have to use the Add method. So I am wondering if there is a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I suspect your code ought to look like like (although its not quite a match for what you currently doing):-

```
public class YourClassHoldingThisStuff : INotifyProperyChanged
{
  private  ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _internal;

  public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> BoundInternal
  {
    get { return _internal; }
    set
    {
      _internal = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("BoundInternal");
    };
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new ProperytChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}
```

In this case the `_internal` field becomes the source of the value of `BoundInternal` directly and you should only assign it via `BoundInternal`, (don't assign a value directly to `_internal`).  When that occurs anything currently bound to it will be informed of the change.

If for some reason you really do need to maintain `_internal` as a separate reference from the backing field of `BoundInternal` then:-

```
public class YourClassHoldingThisStuff : INotifyProperyChanged
{
  private  ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _internal;
  private  ObservableCollection<ViewModel> _boundInternal;

  public ObservableCollection<ViewModel> BoundInternal
  {
    get { return _boundInternal; }
    set
    {
      _boundInternal = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged("BoundInternal");
    };
  }
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new ProperytChangedEventArgs(name));
  }
}
```

Now at some point in your code when you do `BoundInternal = _internal`, anything bound to it will be informed of the change.

Answer (score 3):

Every ItemsControl has a, `Items` property which has a `Refresh()` method that you can call, which will update your list.

`MyList.Items.Refresh()`

Comment: I am not using a list though, I am binding against an ItemsControl

Comment: yes, my code was just an example, your ItemsControl should have the Items property still

Comment: -1, the Items property is protected so you would need to create derived class to access it.  It exposes an `IList<T>` interface which does not have a `Refresh` method.